# Complex Ordering with NHibernate Criteria Queries

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Came across something like this today, and was wondering if there was an equivalent way to solve it in criteria queries.

Basically, there is a table, and this table has two nullable string fields (foo and bar). We wish to sort by the aggregate of these.

string concatenation (`order by foo + bar desc`) returns null if one of the values is null, and `order by foo, bar` doesn't take into account nulls as we wish.

a solution in sql could look like :

```
SELECT foo, bar, (ISNULL(foo,'') + ISNULL(bar,'')) as f
FROM foobar
ORDER BY f DESC
```

I'm not sure of the details within nhibernate's tokenizer, but if you were to write it as

```
SELECT foo, bar
FROM foobar
ORDER BY (ISNULL(foo,'') + ISNULL(bar,'')) DESC
```

using the same query method it chokes because it parses both foo and bar as individual sort expressions.

So...how would you write that in a criteria query? Is there such a method, or would a new ResultTransformer or after-the-fact sorting be the only option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create query-only properties (`access="noop"`, see http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/06/10/nhibernate-ndash-query-only-properties.aspx) with the corresponding formula.

For example,

```
<property name="SortableFoo" formula="ISNULL(foo,'')"/>
```

And you can now `AddOrder` with that "Property".

Comment: very interesting. Sad to see that the solution seems to be at the binding level rather than the criteria level though =/

Comment: Actually, I think it _can_ be done using Projections, SQLFunctions and that kind of stuff... but I think it's even more complicated.
With HQL, on the other hand, it shouldn't be much different from the SQL. Have you tried that?